# Data not getting loaded from WCF RIA to SIlverlight MainPage.xaml.cs

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have created a Silverlight application where i am using WCF RIA services.
My MainPage.xaml.cs is not able to take data from domain service. The method in domain service is

```
public IQueryable<Measurement> GetMeasurements()
{
    return this.ObjectContext.Measurements;
}
```

The code in MainPage.xaml.cs is as below

```
EntityQuery<Measurement> query = from p in service.GetMeasurementsQuery() select p;

LoadOperation<Measurement> measurement = service.Load(query);
```

Please let me know with some advices and suggestions.

Comment: You will get better help if you describe what you _expect_ and what is _actually_ happening. I don't see a problem with your code as you have described it.

Answer (score 1):

The most common misunderstanding with RIA Services is expecting web service calls to be synchronous. In reality, web service calls occur asynchronously. You cannot expect results to be loaded immediately after the Load() call.

```
// creates a query object. It is the equivalent of 
// "SELECT ... FROM ..." as a string. It doesn't actually
// execute the query.
EntityQuery<Measurement> query = 
  from p in service.GetMeasurementsQuery() select p;

// sends the query to the server, but the server doesn't
// return a result in the LoadOperation. The LoadOperation
// will call you back when it is completed.
LoadOperation<Measurement> measurement = service.Load(query);

// when results are available, MeasurementLoaded is called
measurement.Completed += MeasurementLoaded;

// WARNING: do not have any code that expects results here.
// var myMeasurements = service.Measurements;


public void MeasurementLoaded(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
   // you can use service.Measurements now.
   var myMeasurements = service.Measurements;
}
```